# How to install `@tailwindcss/typography` plugin correctly in NextJs?

Tags: next.js, markdown, tailwind-css

Currently, I have a NextJs with tailwindcss project. The project has a blog page that should render markdown content with `.prose` style provided by [tailwind typography plugin](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/typography-plugin).

But, the problem here is that the tailwind typography classes are not generated at all. I'm sure that I have followed all of the [instructions provided in the docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/typography-plugin). And I also tried many things like:

- Restarting my development server much times
- Re-installing the node_module dependencies
- Cleaning npm and yarn caches

But none of them work. The typography classes are not generated and the markdown content is not affected by the `.prose`.

Below are how I use the `.prose`, tailwind config, and `global.css`:

#### src/app/blogs/[slug]/page.tsx :

```js
import MainLayout from "@/components/layouts/MainLayout";
import { BLOGS } from "@/dummy-data/blogs";
import ReactMarkdown from "react-markdown";

const BlogDetailPage = (
  { params, searchParams }: {
    params: { slug: string };
    searchParams?: { [key: string]: string | string[] | undefined };
  }
) => {
  
  const blog = BLOGS.find((blog) => blog.slug === params.slug);
  
  return (
    <MainLayout>
      <div className="">
        <div className="p-4 flex flex-col gap-2">
          <h1 className="text-3xl font-bold">
            {blog?.title}
          </h1>
          
          <article className="prose max-w-prose">
            <ReactMarkdown>
              {blog?.body || "### NO CONTENT"}
            </ReactMarkdown>
          </article>
          
        </div>
      </div>
    </MainLayout>
  );
};

export default BlogDetailPage;
```

#### tailwind.config.ts :

```js
import type { Config } from 'tailwindcss'

const config: Config = {
  content: [
    './src/pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
    './src/components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
    './src/app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      backgroundImage: {
        'gradient-radial': 'radial-gradient(var(--tw-gradient-stops))',
        'gradient-conic':
          'conic-gradient(from 180deg at 50% 50%, var(--tw-gradient-stops))',
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    require('@tailwindcss/typography'),
  ],
}

export default config
```

#### global.css

```css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;


@layer base {
  :root {
    --background: 0 0% 100%;
    --foreground: 222.2 84% 4.9%;

    --card: 0 0% 100%;
    --card-foreground: 222.2 84% 4.9%;

    --popover: 0 0% 100%;
    --popover-foreground: 222.2 84% 4.9%;

    --primary: 222.2 47.4% 11.2%;
    --primary-foreground: 210 40% 98%;

    --secondary: 210 40% 96.1%;
    --secondary-foreground: 222.2 47.4% 11.2%;

    --muted: 210 40% 96.1%;
    --muted-foreground: 215.4 16.3% 46.9%;

    --accent: 210 40% 96.1%;
    --accent-foreground: 222.2 47.4% 11.2%;

    --destructive: 0 84.2% 60.2%;
    --destructive-foreground: 210 40% 98%;

    --border: 214.3 31.8% 91.4%;
    --input: 214.3 31.8% 91.4%;
    --ring: 222.2 84% 4.9%;

    --radius: 0.5rem;
  }

  .dark {
    --background: 222.2 84% 4.9%;
    --foreground: 210 40% 98%;

    --card: 222.2 84% 4.9%;
    --card-foreground: 210 40% 98%;

    --popover: 222.2 84% 4.9%;
    --popover-foreground: 210 40% 98%;

    --primary: 210 40% 98%;
    --primary-foreground: 222.2 47.4% 11.2%;

    --secondary: 217.2 32.6% 17.5%;
    --secondary-foreground: 210 40% 98%;

    --muted: 217.2 32.6% 17.5%;
    --muted-foreground: 215 20.2% 65.1%;

    --accent: 217.2 32.6% 17.5%;
    --accent-foreground: 210 40% 98%;

    --destructive: 0 62.8% 30.6%;
    --destructive-foreground: 210 40% 98%;

    --border: 217.2 32.6% 17.5%;
    --input: 217.2 32.6% 17.5%;
    --ring: hsl(212.7,26.8%,83.9);
  }
}

@layer base {
  * {
    @apply border-border;
  }
  body {
    @apply bg-background text-foreground;
  }
}
```

#### package.json :

```json
{
  "name": "portfolio-fe",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@radix-ui/react-avatar": "^1.0.3",
    "@radix-ui/react-dropdown-menu": "^2.0.5",
    "@radix-ui/react-hover-card": "^1.0.6",
    "@radix-ui/react-separator": "^1.0.3",
    "@radix-ui/react-slot": "^1.0.2",
    "@radix-ui/react-tooltip": "^1.0.6",
    "@tailwindcss/typography": "^0.5.10",
    "@types/node": "20.5.0",
    "@types/react": "18.2.20",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.2.7",
    "@uiw/react-md-editor": "^3.23.5",
    "autoprefixer": "10.4.15",
    "class-variance-authority": "^0.7.0",
    "clsx": "^2.0.0",
    "lucide-react": "^0.268.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "next": "13.4.16",
    "next-mdx-remote": "^4.4.1",
    "postcss": "8.4.28",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.10.1",
    "react-markdown": "^8.0.7",
    "remark-gfm": "^3.0.1",
    "supports-color": "8.1.1",
    "tailwind-merge": "^1.14.0",
    "tailwindcss": "3.3.3",
    "tailwindcss-animate": "^1.0.6",
    "typescript": "5.1.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {}
}
```

And the result is

[image]

As seen above, the content (green) is not affected by the `.prose` form the [@tailwindcss/typography plugin](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/typography-plugin).

Did I miss any step? Or is there any mistake?

Comment: It could be the special characters`[` and `]` in the `[slug]` portion of the file path to `src/app/blogs/[slug]/page.tsx` that Tailwind interprets incorrectly when scanning your source files. See if the code works elsewhere in a file that has no such special characters.

Comment: I already tried it in the `src/app/page.tsx` . But the result is the same as before, it doesn't working.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I was told that the problem in my project is that I have two tailwind configuration files (`tailwind.config.js` and `tailwind.config.ts`). And instead of configuring to add the plugin in the JS configuration file, I configured it in the TS config file. The problem is solved and I will ask to close the question. Thanks.